# The naive kernel density estimator definition

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, estimation, density-function

On B W Silverman [Explanation](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March02/Silverman/paper.pdf) of KDE:

It is stated that from the definition of a probability density, if the random variable X has density f, then

$f(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{1}{2h}\Pr(x-h < X \le x+h) $

And that a natural naive density estimator is

$f(x) =  \dfrac{1}{2hn}[\text{no. of } X_1,..,X_n \text{ falling in }(x-h, x+h)] $

Where is the $\frac{1}{2}$ coming from?

If I have 2 values from a sample of 10 on the $(x-h,x+h)$ range $\Pr(x-h < X \le x+h) = \frac{2}{10}$ how does multiplying by $\frac{1}{2h}$ gives me the density?

Comment: The interval is $2h$ long...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability $2/10$ is the *area* under the density from $x-h$ to $x+h$, which has length $2h$ and has height $f(x)$ when approximating the area by a rectangle, thus

$$
\frac{2}{10} = f(x) \, 2h
$$

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you.